# Identifying lead/lags using multivariate regression analysis

Tags: time-series, arima, multivariate-analysis, regression-coefficients, cross-correlation

I have three time-series variables (x,y,z) measured in 3 replicates.  x and z are the independent variables. y is the dependent variable. t is the time variable. All the three variables follow diel variation, they increase during day and decrease during the night. An example with simulated dataset is below.

```
library(nlme)
library(tidyverse)
n <- 100 
t <- seq(0,4*pi,,100)
a <- 3
b <- 2
c.unif <- runif(n)
#c.norm <- rnorm(n)
amp <- 2

datalist = list()
for(i in 1:3){
y <- 3*sin(b*t)+rnorm(n)*2
x <- 2*sin(b*t+2.5)+rnorm(n)*2
z <- 4*sin(b*t-2.5)+rnorm(n)*2
data = as_tibble(cbind(y,x,z))%>%mutate(t = 1:100)%>% mutate(replicate = i)
datalist[[i]] <- data
}
df <- do.call(rbind,datalist)
ggplot(df)+
  geom_line(aes(t,x),color='red')+geom_line(aes(t,y),color='blue')+
  geom_line(aes(t,z),color = 'green')+facet_wrap(~replicate, nrow = 1)+theme_bw()
```

[image: 1,2,3 are the replicates. red is x. blue is y. and green is z]

I can identify the lead/lag of y with respect to x and z individually. This can be done with ccf() function in r. For example

```
ccf(x,y)
ccf(z,y)
```

But I would like to do it in a multivariate regression approach. For example nlme package and `lme` function indicates y and z are negatively affecting x

```
lme = lme(data = df, y~ x+ z , random=~1|replicate, correlation = corCAR1( form = ~ t| replicate))
```

It is impossible (in actual data) that x and z can negatively affect y.

I need the time-lead/lag and also I would like to get the standardized coefficient (t-value to compare the effect size), both from the same model.

Is there any multivariate model availabe that can give me the lead/lag and also give me regression coefficient?

Comment: Vector AutoRegression (VAR)?

Comment: @RichardHardy  Interesting. ya, something like that. But the problem is the I have replicates that need to be accounted for. Is there r package to do a regression model that can incorporate random variables and also give lead/lag information?